# saving blog post to chrome filesystem blob

Tags: jquery, blogs, html5-filesystem

I am trying to have data (including pictures/links/etc) entered into a jquery text editor saved using the chrome filesystem. I can save as a single file type (say text/plain) but can not figure out how to save the images and the text to the files system at the same time. I essentially want my blog "post" to be saved to the local sandboxed chrome filesystem for later retrieval instead of a server or posting to the webpage...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to save text as well as images, pictures, and links, you should save the blog post as an html file. Assuming your "jquery text editor" has a class `.jquery-textEditor`, a save button with a class of `.save`, and an open button with a class of `.open`, this is how you should open/save that "blog post".

```
//save
var dbName = 'text-vanillajs';
var savedFileEntry, fileEntry;

function getText(callback) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(dbName, function(storedData) {
    var text = $('.jquery-textEditor').html();
    callback(text);
  }.bind(this));
}

function exportToFileEntry(fileEntry) {
  savedFileEntry = fileEntry;
  getText(function(contents) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
      var truncated = false;
      var blob = new Blob([contents]);
      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
        if (!truncated) {
          truncated = true;
          this.truncate(blob.size);
          return;
        }
      };
      fileWriter.write(blob);
    });
  });
}

function ExportToDisk() {
  chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({
    type: 'saveFile',
    suggestedName: 'untitled.html',
    accepts: [{
      description: 'HTML File',
      extensions: ['html']
    }],
    acceptsAllTypes: true
  }, exportToFileEntry);
}

$('.save').click(function() {
  if (savedFileEntry) {
    exportToFileEntry(savedFileEntry);
  } else {
    ExportToDisk();
  }
});
//open
$('.open').click(function(){
  chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({
    type: 'openFile',
    accepts: [{
      extensions: ['html']
    }]
  }, function(fileEntry) {
    if (!fileEntry) {
      return;
    }
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
          var result = e.target.result;
          $('.jquery-textEditor').html(result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    });
  });
});
```